# KineticJS: When do I use toImage() and when do I use cache()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I read that to increase performance you should you use caching. There is a KineticJS tutorial about that: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-shape-caching-with-kineticjs/ It talks about caching but uses the toImage() method.

I could not find an explanation when I should use what.

**What is the difference between these two methods and when do I use cache() or toImage()? Could someone please provide an example for both?**

Edit: Assume you have a layer with three shapes a,b,c. How do I have to cache the layer when I drag one of the shapes? How do I tell KineticJS when to use the cached object?

Is it only this:

```
def layer = // some layer with shape a,b,c


stage.on('dragstart', function() {
        layer.cache();

        // find the shape which is dragged.

      });

stage.on('dragend', function() {
        // ???
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

`myNode.cache` just automates the process of making an image object from the node and using that image object during redraws.

You could do the same thing by doing `myNode.toImage` and then using that image instead of myNode.

Either method speeds drawing because copying image pixels is faster than processing drawing commands to draw the node.

Comment: Could you please provide an example for cache? How do I have to use it on nodes and layers. How do I activate that the image is used from cache?

Comment: Well, .cache does everything needed with that one command. The link you provide in your question is a great demo.  You have a a complex multi-point star that takes a great deal of math to calculate and draw.  Then `star.cache` automatically makes an image of the star and all further drawings use the image to draw the star instead of using the complex math to create and draw the star.

Comment: I did not get it. Could you please explain it on my example. If I do layer.cache(); also the dragged element would be included in the image?

Comment: A common use of layer.cache is when you've composed a complicated background layer.  Then the image-cached version of the layer will be drawn instead of calculating/redrawing each individual shape on the background layer.  So in your edited code if you want to drag element a or b or c individually, you wouldn't cache the layer because you can't individually drag an element anymore (what remains is a picture of the layer with elements a/b/c permanently fixed in place on that layer).  If element a is very complex, you might want to cache just that element:  a.cache  -- but not the whole layer.